# Failed RPC connection to the node 'ejabberd@My-Mac': nodedown

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, chat, ejabberd

I am trying to run ejabberd on Mac OS. I installed the ejabberd-16.06-osx-installer. After that i changed the host name to 'localhost' in ejabberd.yml file. 
   When i run the start command on terminal, i got message like 'Failed RPC connection to the node 'ejabberd@My-Mac': node down'. I checked the log folder, but no error log is generated. 
  Can any one tell me what is going wrong here.

Comment: Edit your config ejabberd.yml file hosts with localhost instead 'ejabberd@My-Mac'